# Microsoft excel 2010- How to have 2 sheets printed on one page in landscape mode

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, printing, landscape

I have an excel worksheet which has nearly 200 columns but only 15 rows. Using page break I managed to have the whole printing area in two PAGES.

Now, I need to have both these PAGES on one landscape page (that is two pages on one sheet), but with both PAGES also in landscape mode, so that I have the whole worksheet displayed on one sheet only - up and down.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This setting will be in your printer settings (if it supports it).

You are looking for a setting such as 'multiple page control' or 'pages per sheet'. Although each printer may be different.